# Make VBA code to run even when MS Access application is open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm an Excel VBA beginner. I have an Excel VBA that opens up a MS Access database and runs a macro to export a query, and then closes the Access application. My code below works, but when there is an already open MS Access instance, it doesn't. I would like to make this work so I don't have to close the Access.

```
Sub GetAccess()
'Open MS Access accdb file then run the macro to export Excel file


'Bind to an existing or created instance of Microsoft Access
Dim objApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set objApp = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Could not get instance, so create a new one
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    With objApp
        .Visible = True
    End With
Else
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
End If


'Process this if successfully bound to MS Access application
objApp.Visible = False
objApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("Y:\Civil Site Development Engineers Group\Civil Team Task Monitoring\Export To Excel.accdb")
objApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Ron_Export_Query"
objApp.Quit

'Inform User Database Excel file is updated
MsgBox "Database Updated"


'Timestamp
Range("I1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.Value = Range("I1") & " " & Date & " " & Time


'Unprotect Worksheet
Worksheets("Ron_qryCiviRecords_Query").Unprotect "CivilTeam"


'Update Excel Linked formulas
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks


'Protect Worksheet
Worksheets("Ron_qryCiviRecords_Query").Protect Password:="CivilTeam", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
AllowSorting:=False, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Save Excel File
ActiveWorkbook.Save


ErrHandler:
'Release the object and resume normal error handling
Set objApp = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like exactly?  What happens when you run that?

Comment: First thing to do in such situations: disable your error handling, so you see where what happens. In this particular case: your error handler `ErrHandler:` doesn't _report_ an error at all.

Comment: Thanks Tim, When I click the button it does nothing, I will to need to disable error handler as Hel suggested to give you more info.

Comment: Thanks Hel, I could try disabling the error handler to give more info but I could try that after weekend.

Comment: Is it the else statement that is making it not to work when there is an instance of MS Accesss?  Sorry for the beginner questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to it figure out.  I just have to create a new object connection for both true and false checks of the line "If Err.Number <> 0".